# Smooth transition when modal gets visible in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I made modal in React and it's working fine, but I really want to add one small feature. When I'm clicking on button, class of modal is changing and modal is becoming visible, but this happens immediately and I want to add some transition.

My code:
In parent method toggling class and passing props:

```
toggleModal() {
  this.setState({ visibleModal: !this.state.visibleModal });
}

<RegisterModal
  visible={this.state.visibleModal}
  toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
/>
```

Children component:

```
<div className={`modal ${props.visible ? 'modal--visible' : 'modal--invisible'}`}>
```

My CSS:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal--invisible {
  display: none;
}

.modal--visible {
  display: flex;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `and I want to add some transition` Ok, what transition? Fade in? In from the left? From the top down? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834063/fade-in-out-effect-on-after-before-element-with-css/49834485#49834485)

The `display` property can't change smoothly, it only has fixed values. It jumps instantly from one to the next. You need to use `transition` and something like `opacity` to get a nice fade in.

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity .5s; /* Opacity will fade smoothly */
}

.modal--invisible {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /* Makes the modal unclickable */
}

.modal--visible {
   opacity: 1; /* Modal is visible */
   pointer-events: initial; /* Modal is clickable */
}
```